# how i can add this scan a number and settext automatically like this application?

Tags: android, camera

like this application I would to scan a number of card recharge mobile and subtext automatically

[image]

Comment: You can use Google's Vision API.

Comment: you have an exemple ? thank you

Comment: Yes, Check [This](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/08/android-barcode-scanner-using-google-mobile-vision-building-movie-tickets-app/)

Comment: thank you  Ümañg ßürmån but this for  only Android Barcode / QR Code Scanner

Comment: Yeah I do understand it, I just showed you as an example that similarly even your question might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tesseract to make OCR(Object Character Recognizer) Application
 https://github.com/yushulx/android-tesseract-ocr use this link for more information